# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended run just in the client

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I'm starting to develop in PL/SQL, I am using the version of Oracle 10g and have a seemingly simple problem.

The same code in the  PL/SQL client is working well,  the query run  without error.
but when I run by SQL *PLUS, him show me the following error;

```
(select campagne_id,
                  *
```

> ERROR at line 13: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Below you can see the code, please if someone have a suggestion please post for me.

```
set underline off
set NEWP NONE
set feed     off
set heads    off
set hea      off
set verify   off
set trims    on
set pagesize 50000
set linesize 32767
spool /home/dsadm/br/sh_synchro/data/elison/report_usa.csv
select 'CAMPAIGN_ID'||chr(9)||'CAMPAIGN_NAME'||chr(9)||'SEND_DATE'||chr(9)||'MESSAGE'||chr(9)||'SUBJECT'||chr(9)||'SELECTED'||chr(9)||'OPENS_NB'||chr(9)||'OPENED_P'||chr(9)||'TOTAL_CLICKS'||chr(9)||'CLICK_THROUGHS_NB'||chr(9)||'CLICK_THROUGH'||chr(9)||'ACTION_CLICKS' FROM DUAL;
select t1.campanha_id ||chr(9)|| t1.name||chr(9)|| t1.dateenvio||chr(9)|| t1.subject||chr(9)|| t1.nb_selected||chr(9)|| t1.nb_opened||chr(9)|| trunc(t3.opened_p, 2)||chr(9)|| t1.nb_total_click||chr(9)||t3.clickthrough||chr(9)||trunc(t3.clickthrough_p, 2)||chr(9)||t2.clickes
from (select rc.nb_selected,`RC.NB_OPENED NB_OPENED,
           RC.NB_TOTAL_CLICK NB_TOTAL_CLICK,
           c.name NAME,
           c.dateenvoi DATEENVIO,
           m.subject SUBJECT,
           c.campagne_id CAMPANHA_ID
      FROM report_campagne rc, campagne c, message m
     WHERE c.campagne_id = rc.campagne_id
       and c.ctype=0
       and m.message_id = c.message_id
       and c.campagne_id=1926832) t1,

   (select sum(nb_clicks) as clickes, l.campaign_id as campanha_id
      from url u, report_camp_link l
     where u.url_id = l.link_id
       and u.type = 3
       and u.client_id = 1101001556
       and l.campaign_id in
           (select campagne_id
              from campagne
             where client_id = 1101001556
               and ctype=0
               and campagne_id=1926832)
     group by l.campaign_id) t2,(select campagne_id,
           sum(decode(r.status, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0)) opens,
           case
             when (sum(decode(r.status, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0))) > 0 then
              (sum(decode(r.status, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0)) /
              sum(decode(r.status, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0))) * 100
             else
              0
           end opened_p,
           sum(r.regular_click_nb) total_clicks,
           sum(decode(r.status, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0)) clickthrough,
           case
             when (sum(decode(r.status, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0))) > 0 then
              (sum(decode(r.status, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0)) /
              sum(decode(r.status, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0))) * 100
             else
              0
           end clickthrough_p
      from worldnetdaily_report r
     where CAMPAGNE_ID in
           (select campagne_id
              from campagne
             where client_id = 1101001556
               and ctype=0
               and campagne_id=1926832)
     group by campagne_id) t3`where t1.campanha_id = t2.CAMPANHA_ID
and t2.campanha_id = t3.campagne_id(+)
and t3.campagne_id = t1.campanha_id(+);
spool on
quit`
```

Comment: this looks funny:  t3`where

Comment: You think that this is my problem ? How can run perfectly in PL/SQL DEVELOPER, only when I trying run by SQL*PLUS this issue happens???

Comment: i see one other single quote - these look like mismatched - maybe cut and paste error?

Comment: No, this was when I put the code in here! the code don't has it single quote.

Comment: @MárcioCorrea, do you have an empty line? could it be the same problem as this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406810/sqlplus-does-not-execute-sql-scripts-that-sql-developer-does ?

Comment: Hi, My script is working very well, Thanks very much for your help!