# Oracle Function Script Compile Error

Tags: oracle, function, compilation

I have function script. In it there is two function like:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  "FUNC1" (
    MJOB_CODE IN VARCHAR2,
    MOP_CODE  IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN DATE
   IS
    RETDATE DATE;
   BEGIN

--SOMETHING--
     RETURN(RETDATE);
   END;
/

  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  "FUNC2" (
    MJOB_CODE IN VARCHAR2,
    MOP_CODE  IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN DATE
   IS
    RETDATE DATE;
   BEGIN

--SOMETHING--
     RETURN(RETDATE);
   END;
```

But im getting error and when i look function in functions, I see that like function compiled like this:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  "FUNC1" (
    MJOB_CODE IN VARCHAR2,
    MOP_CODE  IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN DATE
   IS
    RETDATE DATE
```

A part of code is missing. Actualy after `;` part is missing.

If i put create function block into this missing code and compile i works. But i have too many function so i dont want to use that.

How can i solve this problem? How can i compile functions in script?

Comment: Could it be the same problem as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406810/sqlplus-does-not-execute-sql-scripts-that-sql-developer-does

Comment: Do you use SQL*Plus for the compilation ?

Comment: --Emmanuel: I use ORACLE sql developer  Version 3.2.20.09 
--A.B.Cade: 'set sqlbl on' didnt work for me. Can you explain your solution more?

Comment: @SercanSülün, it's only for sqlplus... How do you run your script? with F9 or F5 ? does it make any difference ?

Comment: @A.B.Cade Both. It's no use. I can do it from another computer's sql developer. I think that about preference of sql developer...