# Error loading a file in oracle

Tags: oracle, loading

im working with oracle right now, but im getting a problem when a load this .sql file

```
 CREATE TABLE TIENDA(

  ID_TIEND       NUMBER,
  NOMB_TIEND     VARCHAR2(40),
  RIF            VARCHAR2 (15),
  TELF           VARCHAR2 (15),
  FAX            VARCHAR2 (15),
  CAPACIDAD_PROD NUMBER,
  ID_CIUD        NUMBER,
  CONSTRAINT ID_TIEND_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID_TIEND),

 );

 CREATE TABLE CATEGORIA(
  ID_CAT   NUMBER,
  NOMB_CAT VARCHAR2(20),
  CONSTRAINT ID_CAT_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID_CAT)
 );

 CREATE TABLE SUBCATEGORIA(
  ID_SUB   NUMBER,
  NOMB_SUB VARCHAR2(20),
  ID_CAT   NUMBER,
  CONSTRAINT ID_SUB_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID_SUB),

 );

 CREATE TABLE MARCA(
  ID_MARCA   NUMBER,
  NOMB_MARCA VARCHAR2 (20),
  CONSTRAINT ID_MARCA_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID_MARCA)
 );  

  CREATE TABLE PROVEEDOR(
  ID_PROV NUMBER,
  NOMBRE  VARCHAR2(30),
  RIF   VARCHAR2(15),
  TELF    VARCHAR2(15),
  ID_CIUD NUMBER,
  CONSTRAINT ID_PROV_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID_PROV),

 );

 CREATE TABLE ESTADO(
  ID_EST   NUMBER,
  NOMB_EST VARCHAR2(20),
  SIGLAS   VARCHAR2 (2),
  CONSTRAINT ID_EST_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID_EST)    
  );

 CREATE TABLE CIUDAD(
  ID_CIUD   NUMBER,
  NOMB_CIUD VARCHAR2(20),
  SIGLAS    VARCHAR2(2),
  ID_EST    NUMBER,
  CONSTRAINT ID_CIUD_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID_CIUD),

 );

 CREATE TABLE PROVEE(
  FECHA_REC   DATE,
  FECHA_ENV   DATE,
  CANT        NUMBER,
  ID_PROV     NUMBER,
  ID_ALM      NUMBER,
  ID_PROD     NUMBER,
  COSTO_PROD  FLOAT,
  COSTO_ENV   FLOAT,
  COSTO_TOTAL FLOAT,
  CONSTRAINT FECHA_PK PRIMARY KEY (FECHA_REC,FECHA_ENV),

 );

 CREATE TABLE ABASTECE (
  FECHA_REC  DATE,
  FECHA_DESC DATE,
  ID_ALM     NUMBER, 
  ID_TIEND   NUMBER,
  ID_PROD    NUMBER,
  CANT       NUMBER,
  CONSTRAINT FECHA_PK PRIMARY KEY (FECHA_REC,FECHA_DESC),

 );

 CREATE TABLE PRODUCTO(
  ID_PROD     NUMBER,
  NOMBRE_PROD VARCHAR2(30),
  ID_MARCA    NUMBER,
  ID_SUB      NUMBER,
  PVP         FLOAT,
  CONSTRAINT ID_PROD_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID_PROD),

 );

 CREATE TABLE TIENDA(
  ID_TIEND       NUMBER,
  NOMB_TIEND     VARCHAR2(40),
  RIF            VARCHAR2 (15),
  TELF           VARCHAR2 (15),
  FAX            VARCHAR2 (15),
  CAPACIDAD_PROD NUMBER,
  ID_CIUD        NUMBER,
  CONSTRAINT ID_TIEND_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID_TIEND),

 );

 CREATE TABLE ALMACEN(
  ID_ALM         NUMBER,
  NOMB_ALM       VARCHAR2(40),
  RIF            VARCHAR2(15),
  TELF           VARCHAR2(15),
  DIMENSIONES    VARCHAR2(15),
  CAPACIDAD_PROD NUMBER,
  ID_CIUD        NUMBER,
  CONSTRAINT ID_ALM_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID_ALM),

 );



 CREATE TABLE TIENE(
  FECHA      DATE, 
  ID_TIEND   NUMBER,
  ID_PROD    NUMBER
  CANT_VEND  NUMBER,
  CANT_EXIST NUMBER,
  NOPA       NUMBER,
  NMRD       NUMBER,
  CONSTRAINT FECHA_PK PRIMARY KEY (FECHA), 

 );

 CREATE TABLE ALMACENA(
  FECHA      DATE,
  ID_ALM     NUMBER,
  ID_PROD    NUMBER,
  CANT_DESP  NUMBER,
  CANT_EXIST NUMBER,
  NOPAL      NUMBER, 
  NMRS       NUMBER,
  CONSTRAINT FECHA_PK PRIMARY KEY (FECHA),

 );

  ALTER TABLE SUBCATEGORIA
  ADD CONSTRAINT ID_SUB_FK
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_CAT)
  REFERENCES CATEGORIA(ID_CAT);

  ALTER TABLE CIUDAD
  ADD CONSTRAINT ID_EST_FK
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_EST)
  REFERENCES ESTADO(ID_EST);

  ALTER TABLE PROVEE
  ADD CONSTRAINT ID_PROV_FK
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_PROV)
  REFERENCES PROVEEDOR(ID_PROV);

  ALTER TABLE PROVEE
  ADD CONSTRAINT ID_ALM_FK
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_ALM)
  REFERENCES ALMACEN(ID_ALM);

  ALTER TABLE PROVEE
  ADD CONSTRAINT ID_PROD_FK
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_PROD)
  REFERENCES PRODUCTO(ID_PROD);

  ALTER TABLE ABASTECE
  ADD CONSTRAINT ID_TIEND_FK
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_TIEND)
  REFERENCES TIENDA(ID_TIEND);

  ALTER TABLE ABASTECE
  ADD CONSTRAINT ID_PROD_FK
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_PROD)
  REFERENCES PRODUCTO(ID_PROD);

  ALTER TABLE ABASTECE
  ADD CONSTRAINT ID_ALM_FK
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_ALM)
  REFERENCES ALMACEN(ID_ALM);

  ALTER TABLE PRODUCTO
  ADD CONSTRAINT ID_SUBC_FK
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_SUB)
  REFERENCES SUBCATEGORIA(ID_SUB);

  ALTER TABLE TIENDA
  ADD CONSTRAINT ID_CIUD_FK
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_CIUD)
  REFERENCES CIUDAD(ID_CIUD);

  ALTER TABLE ALMACEN
  ADD CONSTRAINT ID_CIUD_FK
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_CIUD)
  REFERENCES CIUDAD(ID_CIUD);

  ALTER TABLE PROVEEDOR
  ADD CONSTRAINT ID_CIUD_FK
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_CIUD)
  REFERENCES CIUDAD(ID_CIUD);

  ALTER TABLE TIENE
  ADD CONSTRAINT ID_TIEND_FK
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_TIEND)
  REFERENCES TIENDA(ID_TIEND);  

  ALTER TABLE TIENE
  ADD CONSTRAINT ID_PROD_FK
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_PROD)
  REFERENCES PRODUCTO(ID_PROD);

  ALTER TABLE ALMACENA
  ADD CONSTRAINT ID_ALM_FK
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_ALM)
  REFERENCES ALMACEN(ID_ALM);

  ALTER TABLE ALMACENA
  ADD CONSTRAINT ID_PROD_FK
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_PROD)
  REFERENCES PRODUCTO(ID_PROD);
```

When i load it in the terminal with this command "SQL> start D:\lab2.sql" this error comes out

[image]

A little help? thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL\*Plus does not execute SQL scripts that SQL Developer does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406810/sqlplus-does-not-execute-sql-scripts-that-sql-developer-does)

Answer (score 0):

In some of your commands - e.g. the first one - you seem to have removed a line before the ending parenthesis. But you have not at the same time removed the trailing comma from the preceding line.

I cant say if this will solve all your errors - but certainly some:-)